# How can I put Media Player Classic only in full screen, without a toggle?

Tags: windows, media, player

There's a few options in Media Player Classic to set it on full screen, you can typically press `Alt+Enter` or `F`, but both of those options will toggle it so if it's playing in full screen already, it will bring it out of full screen.

An option I am trying to work out is, where a key combination puts it in full screen if it's not already... and if it already is in full screen, pressing the key combination does nothing (just tries to make it full screen when it already is, so it just stays full screen).

I have looked in the options by searching for "screen" and it seems that it just doesn't exist.

The reason I ask is, I am using an automated script that exports an Adobe Premiere MP4 then a batch file runs to play the last modified MP4, that opens in Media Player Classic. I may or may not have had Media Player Classic on full screen the last time I used it, so simply having it send the `F` key to Media Player Classic isn't going to work, because that's just a toggle from full screen to windowed or vice versa.

Is it just not possible to do this in Media Player Classic?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out on the command line, where the `/fullscreen` switch isn't a toggle, it means literally full screen only, so that works:

```
start mpc-hc64.exe "video_file.mp4" /fullscreen
```

It doesn't matter how you last closed MPC, the above way forces full screen, always.